# Convert png/jpg to word file using python

Tags: python, png, jpeg, converters

I need to convert lots of jpg/png files to docx files & then to pdf. My sole concern is to write the data in an image to a pdf file & if I need to edit any text manually, I can do that in word & save it in the corresponding pdf file.

I've tried using API but failed as the text is not correctly matching.

My image files contain only texts & not anything else.

I already have docx to pdf conversion code in Python.

```
from docx2pdf import convert

input = 'INPUT_FILE_NAME.docx'
output = 'OUTPUT_FILE_NAME.pdf'
convert(input)
convert(input, output)
convert("Output")
```

Kindly suggest me how to convert a png/jpg file to docx. Thanks.

EDIT --------------

I've successfully made this code run. I've uploaded in my [github repo](https://github.com/nitinkumar30/imageFileToPdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import pytesseract

#Define path to tessaract.exe
path_to_tesseract = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'


#Define path to image
path_to_image = 'texttoimage.png'

#Point tessaract_cmd to tessaract.exe
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract

#Open image with PIL
img = Image.open(path_to_image)

#Extract text from image
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

print(text)
```

Comment: Do I need to download tesseract.exe too as indicated from the code -  

`path_to_tesseract = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'`

Comment: Thanks, working code. We need to download [tesseract](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki).

64 bit from [here](https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.2.0.20220712.exe)